# Vertical centering anchors inside floated list items

Tags: css, css-float, centering

I've got a simple menu like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">Products</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The list elements of the unordered list are floated to the left and have a fixed `height`:

```
ul.menu li {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexxus/QNMy7/2/)

Now I would like to vertically center the anchors inside the list elements.

What is the best approach for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To vertically center text, set a `line-height` to the same value as the height of the element. Seeing as you have a set height, this will work with no problems:

```
.menu li a {
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QNMy7/3/

Comment: This works, thanks. Can I remove the height property from the `li` elements now? It's kind of redundant now as I concern

Comment: If you remove the height of the li element, it might screw up the centering of the text. The line-height tells the heights of each line of text to be 50px tall, the same as the element's height so it matches up. IF you have more than one line, the next line will not be seen.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks Maybe then it's a better idea to set the `line-height` on the `.menu li` like suggested by Airen?

Comment: You can do that, but you still need the height.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks I know, but it's a bit cleaner, because I do not have to declare `.menu li a` if I don't have it already. I think it's a good alternative to your answer

Answer (score 2):

add line-height equal the height:

```
.menu li {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    **line-height: 50px;**
    padding: 0 10px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: +1 for adding the `line-height` to the `.menu li`. See my comments to Kyle Sevenoaks's answer

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu li {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: yellow;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 100px;
}

.menu li a
{
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with `.menu li` class. You have declared a `float` for it to move to the left, but to make it `vertically-aligned`, you have to remove the `float` and apply a `display:table-cell;` to get the `vertical-alignment` working.

**For Instance,**

```
.menu li {
    /*float: left;*/
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Here is the [WORKING SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/QNMy7/4/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: What? Since when do you _need_ to have `display: table-cell;` to enable vertical centering. Sure this is _one_ method of doing it, but it isn't the only one.

Comment: Yes. It is one of the methods of doing it and not the only one. - @KyleSevenoaks

Comment: I don't want to remove `float`. The list elements shall remain floated to the left

Answer (score 0):

You can use `line-height` to control vertical alignment, but this only works reliably across each list item if they're all restricted to one line.

The most reliable way to achieve this is by removing the float & displaying the list item as a CSS `table-cell`:

```
.menu {
    display: table;
}

.menu li {
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.menu li a {
    display: block;
}
```

This way, if one of the links drops onto two lines, it's still vertically centered, as shown here:

http://jsfiddle.net/QNMy7/6/

Comment: [That is correct and already answered.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064436/vertical-centering-anchors-inside-floated-list-items/17064554#17064554)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to float and table-cell, you can also use inline-block:

```
.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.menu li a {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Similar to the other posts, I set `line-height: 50px` on `.menu li` and `vertical-align: middle` on the `a` elements.  You can omit the height in this example.

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/QNMy7/7/

Comment: `inline-block` adds the nasty spaces between the elements. I already tried that before posting

Comment: Indeed, these nasty little spaces are annoying at times.  In some cases, the layout calls for left/right margins between the elements, so this does not become an issue.  The little spaces disappear if the html code does not contain extra white space, but that is also a nuisance.  If you need elements to align edge-to-edge, floats are the way to go.

Comment: There is an article on removing the nasty spaces on [css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/). But after reading it I desided to stick to the floats

Comment: The one case where inline-block is useful and easier to use is when you want to create a horizontal menu and you want the links to be centered on the page instead of flush to the left or right.